# Sub Query and JOINs

Tags: mysql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group, correlated-subquery

I have 3 tables concerning complains. The first table consists of the complain information itself, 2nd one is the complain_review with status_id, and the 3rd is the status_id table consisting status information. I'm trying to select the complain_desc from complain and latest status_id from complain_review (sort by date desc) and couple that with complain_status information.

This is what I've tried (no success so far):

```
SELECT c1.complain_desc, c2.status_id, c2.name as statusDesc from complain c1 
left join
(SELECT c3.status_id, c4.name, c3.complain_id FROM complain_review c3
inner join complain_status c4 on c4.id=c3.status_id ORDER by c3.date DESC) c2 
on c2.complain_id=c1.id
```

this is the updated example provided by @maheshiv

.. I've searched through the site but I don't exactly know what keyword to search concerning this matter :(

Edit: I've build a schema at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d86a7a/2 so perhaps somebody could give take a better look at the tables

Edit: Perhaps this would be the closest as I could get .. and working!

```
SELECT c.complain_desc, cr1.status_id, cs.name
  FROM complain c
  INNER JOIN complain_review cr1 ON c.id=cr1.complain_id
  INNER JOIN complain_status cs ON cs.id=cr1.status_id
  WHERE cr1.date = (SELECT MAX(cr2.date) FROM complain_review cr2
```

WHERE cr1.complain_id=cr2.complain_id)

Comment: can you show us all of the column names for all 3 tables?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Where is 3rd table?

Comment: I've edited the question with table informations

Comment: I think we are still missing information. If ID if the primary key on all tables, how can you have more than status?

Comment: the complain_id in complain_review table is foreign key to table complain .. while status_id in complain_review table to complain_status

Comment: @Jeebsion, could you check my updated answer?

Comment: @maheshiv not exactly precise .. you did MAX(status_id) instead of using date ... I'm trying to get the latest status_id .. so therefore it's natural to use date instead ... :(

Comment: Anyways latest status_id will be maximum status-id right?

Comment: @maheshiv actually the use of MAX is actually the maximum value of the type described for the schema .. I found another way of doing it .. I'd be fixing the answer in a bit .. tried running through sql fiddle but failed something went wrong though .. perhaps you can try it :D

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to select the complain_desc from complain and latest status_id from complain_review (sort by date desc) and couple that with complain_status information.

This is a very common question on Stack Overflow. You can follow the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) to find many solutions.

Here's a solution using your example:

```
SELECT c.complain_desc, latest_cr.status_id, cs.name AS status_desc
FROM complain AS c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT complain_id, status_id 
    FROM (
        SELECT cr.complain_id, cr.status_id, 
          IF(@cgroup=cr.complain_id, @rownum:=@rownum+1, 1) AS rownum,
          (@cgroup:=cr.complain_id)
        FROM (SELECT @cgroup:=0, @rownum:=1) AS _init
        CROSS JOIN complain_review AS cr
        ORDER BY cr.complain_id DESC, cr.date DESC
    ) AS n
    WHERE n.rownum = 1 
) AS latest_cr 
  ON c.id=latest_cr.complain_id
INNER JOIN complain_status AS cs
  ON cs.id = latest_cr.status_id;
```

Here's a different solution using no subqueries:

```
SELECT c.complain_desc, cr1.status_id, cs.name AS status_desc
FROM complain AS c
INNER JOIN complain_review AS cr1
  ON cr1.complain_id = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN complain_review AS cr2
  ON cr2.complain_id = c.id AND (cr2.date > cr1.date OR cr2.date = cr1.date AND cr2.id > cr1.id)
INNER JOIN complain_status AS cs
  ON cs.id = cr1.status_id
WHERE cr2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: OMG .. the first solution seems very complicated with the use of '@cgroup' and '@rownum', etc ... can I ask you for the explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may need this query, 
I believe max status_id is the latest status for complaint. As per http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d86a7a/15

```
select c1.complain_desc, c2.status_id, c3.name from complain c1 inner join (select complain_id, max(status_id) from complain_review group by complain_id) c2 on c1.id=c2.complain_id inner join complain_status c3 on c3.id=c2.status_id;
```

Comment: err .. I only need the latest status_id ... though I've tried the statement to no success :(

Comment: it's not working .. nothing comes out from the query :(

Comment: Could you explain me what is your requirement?
Your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry .. my session ended as it didn't response any result earlier .. now that I've tried the statement there seems to be repetition of the same result from complain table with different status_id ... oh dear ...

Comment: I wanted to list all complain_desc from table complain with the latest status_id from the complain_review table with description from the complain_status table ... yep .. like that

Comment: hold on .. lemme try to build the complete table schema and on sql fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129068/discussion-between-maheshiv-and-jeebsion).